# Size of linearly independent set bounded by the size of a spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How would I go about proving this theorem?

- Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$, $\{u_1, ..., u_m\} \subseteq V$ be linearly independent & let $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ span $V$.
- Then $m \leq N$, (i.e size of linearly independent sets bounded by the size of spanning sets).

Comment: Does this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195327/proving-that-m-leq-n-using-finite-spanning-sets-and-linear-independence?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head,  we know that $\dim V\le n$, since the dimension is the size of a minimal spanning set.

But if $m>n$, we get $\dim V\ge m\gt n \rightarrow\leftarrow$.

Comment: just to mention, the definition of dimension hasn't been covered yet in this textbook, so I'm supposed to prove this without using the notion of dimension.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll give it another go